# Size of the largest balanced binary subtree

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree, graph-algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to create a divide-and-conquer algorithm that, when run on the root of a binary tree, returns the size of the largest balanced binary subtree contained within the tree or in other words, the size of the largest subtree possible where the leaves are all at the same depth.

Comment: Only one traversal is needed: write a recursive function, which returns two numbers for a node: `a`: the largest balanced subtree seen (this is the output) and `b`: if the node has balanced children, then returns the depth. If doesn't have balanced children, return 0. You can calculate `b` for a node by calling recursively. If the returned depths match, then you can return depth+1 for `b`, otherwise zero. And you need to update `a` with `b`. That's all.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow. Can you elaborate further? Why do you return two numbers for a node? Why do you return depth + 1 for b if the returned depths match? And what do you update a with b with?

Comment: returning 2 numbers are needed, because one (b) stores the current depth, which can be zero, if the node is unbalanced. So a is needed to store the current maximum seen, which cannot decrease. By update, I mean a simple if: if (a<b) a = b;. If both children return non-zero depth for b, then you need to return depth+1 for b, because the node is balanced, and its depth is depth+1.

Comment: Can you stop vandalizing your posts? If you'd like to have your posts deleted, flag for moderator attention.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate of the linked question. Unfortunately many of the details that were originally in the question have been deleted by the user. I'm new to SO, but I don't understand why my answer, which I believe did address the original question, has now received a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Some code might help. This is Java, but it's pretty generic.

```
static class Node
{
    String val;
    Node left, right;
}

static class MaxNode
{
    Node node;
    int depth;
}

static int depth(Node node)
{
    if(node.left == null && node.right == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

static int deepestSubtree(Node root, MaxNode maxNode)
{
    if(root == null) return 0;

    int depth = depth(root);

    int leftDepth = deepestSubtree(root.left, maxNode); 
    int rightDepth = deepestSubtree(root.right, maxNode);

    if(leftDepth == rightDepth) 
    {
        depth += leftDepth;
    }

    if(depth > maxNode.depth) 
    {
        maxNode.node = root;
        maxNode.depth = depth;
    }

    return depth;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Node root = buildTree();

    MaxNode maxNode = new MaxNode();
    deepestSubtree(root, maxNode);
    if(maxNode.node == null)
    {
        System.out.println("No Balanced Tree");
    }
    else
    {
        int size = (int)Math.pow(2, maxNode.depth+1)-1;
        System.out.format("Node: %s, Depth: %d, Size: %d\n", maxNode.node.val, maxNode.depth, size);
    }
}
```

For your example tree the output is:

```
Node: D, Depth: 2, Size: 7
```